# Get user email afer whitelist PHP

Tags: php, email, twitter

I am working with a PHP Twitter Login system & I have requested my Twitter application to be on a Twitter whitelist, so that I can get email from a user when he register with Twitter on my website.

My application was successfully whitelisted, but I didn't find any tutorial how to get email in PHP code.

There is a part of the index.php code:
//Variables del usuario

```
        $tw_name        = $_SESSION['request_vars']['screen_name'];
        $tw_id          = $_SESSION['request_vars']['user_id'];
        $oauth_key      = $_SESSION['request_vars']['oauth_token'];
        $oauth_secret_key = $_SESSION['request_vars']['oauth_token_secret'];

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_key, $oauth_secret_key);
        $my_data = $connection->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => $tw_name, 'user_id'=> $tw_id));
        $my_tweets = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $screen_name, 'count' => 10));       
        $my_email = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials', array('screen_name' => $tw_name, 'user_id'=> $tw_id,'include_email'=>true));

echo '<strong>Name:</strong> '.$my_data->name.
        '<br><strong>Date: </strong> ' .$my_data->created_at.
        '<br><strong>Description:</strong> ' .$my_data->description.
        '<br><strong>Location:</strong> ' .$my_data->location.
        '</br><strong>Lenguage:</strong> '.$my_data->lang.'<br>';
        echo $my_email->email;
```

I can see name, date, etc but i can't with the user email, help

Comment: Did you check twitter API? I guess it does not return user email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the content of dumping `$my_email`? It could be a error or a described behaviour, in the twitter docs:

> "When set to true email will be returned in the user objects as a
>   string. If the user does not have an email address on their account,
>   or if the email address is un-verified, null will be returned."

It could be the case?

If no, you could try doing this way:

```
$my_email = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials", ['include_entities' => true, 'skip_status' => true, 'include_email' => true]);
```

or simply:

```
get("account/verify_credentials", ['include_email' => true]);
```

With pure booleans instead of strings, found here: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/364 and reading the official documention: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials it makes sense.

If this doesn't work (that it should), in some others places, they use only:

```
$data = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

(http://code.runnable.com/UnUm0Nx6Lu1MAAAY/how-to-use-twitter-oauth-in-php-web-application-for-twitteroauth)

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are welcomed! Mark the question as solved (check the tick of the answer) and if the response helps you, upvote ;)